# Understanding floating points and infinite loops

Tags: java, loops, infinite

I have this code:

```
while (x < 10.0) {
    x += y;
}
```

If `x` and `y` are floating point numbers, apparently if you add them the loop will continue infinitely. I don't understand how it wont pass 10. It seems impossible to not pass ten but it doesn't according to my text book.

Why is that? Is it because of the rounding that happens with floating points? Or am I missing something?

Edit: `x` and `y` are strictly postive by the way

Comment: It depends on the values of `x` and `y`.  What are they?

Comment: try to put `System.out.println(x)` inside loop to track how much increment each loop get

Comment: the values of x and y are relevant. if y = 0, this is obviously an infinite loop (if x < 10) :)

Comment: guys their strictly positive so both x and y are above 0. Meaning if they loop through it will increment past 10.

Comment: @user1832483: No that's not true.

Comment: OK, @OliCharlesworth knows the trick.  I'm not seeing it myself, though ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't told us the actual initial values of `x` or `y`, so we can't say for sure.  But here's an example of why this might not work:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float x = 1.0f;
        float y = 1e-8f;
        float z = x + y;

        System.out.printf("%g\n", x);      // 1.00000
        System.out.printf("%g\n", y);      // 1.00000e-08
        System.out.printf("%g\n", z);      // 1.00000
        System.out.printf("%g\n", z - x);  // 0.00000

    }
}
```

See http://ideone.com/RMMPlP.

Comment: And an example where it could theoretically work, you just haven't waited long enough: `y = 1e-30f` :-)

Comment: Yes see this is what I mean I plugged in the code and it just keeps running but why is that thought what makes floating point numbers just keep going like that.

Comment: @user1832483: Because in floating point, 1.0 + 1e-8 == 1.0.  You need to review how floating-point works ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I just meant to joke that even if the precision was sufficient so adding 1e-30f would result in a higher value, because the loop would have to iterate about 1e30 times it would effectively be an infinite loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your y value may be 0 or very small and hence making the loop to run for infinte or for a long time:

Assuming if

```
y = 0;
```

This loop will go infinite

```
while(x < 10.0) {
x += y;
}
```

Comment: i understood this but the problem is that x and y are strictly positive so y or x cant be 0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java?Try this-

```
while(x < 10.0f) {
x += y;
}
```

or

```
while(x < (float)10.0) {
x += y;
}
```